# Object.assign this with NodeList

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm building a simple DOM utility library, similar to jQuery is ES6.

```
class jQuery {

    constructor(selector) {            
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        Object.assign(this, elements);
    }
}

let $ = selector => new jQuery(selector);

console.log($('h1'));
```

I'm trying to merge this with my elements, both types are objects but the results its just an empty object (this).

But, if I merge `this` with `{ foo: 'bar' }` its working.

Can someone explain me why this is happening?

Live at https://jsbin.com/zupece/edit?js,console,output

Comment: `Object.assign(this, {elements});` just provide a key for the arraylike you're assigning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `NodeList` does not support `get` the way you want it to, which is used by [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

You could just assign it as an composite:

```
class jQuery {

    constructor(selectorOrElement) {

        this.elements = selectorOrElement instanceof HTMLElement ? [selectorOrElement] : document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }

    addClass(className) {

        this.elements.forEach(function (element) {

            element.classList.push(element);
        });
    }

    each(callback) {

        for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {

            var scope = this.elements[i];
            callback.call(scope, i, new jQuery(scope)); 
        }
    }
}
```

This is more OOP anyway. Besides, various JavaScript engines can now try to optimize your code for better performance. This is much less possible while using `Object.assign`.

Comment: but if i dont merge with the constructor, then i cant access other methods in my class, like add class\

Comment: what if I want to do like $('h1').each(function(el) { el.addClass('test')  }); dosent work, how jquery makes to access $(this) anyway?

Comment: @Hiero See edit, that will work with what you suggest.

Comment: `instanceof HtmlElement` might likely fail for other nodes or in browsers not supporting this interface. Rather test for the selector, which you know to be a string. Also, you should use a `for of` loop instead of `forEach`.

Comment: i check if selector has nodeType, its more safe

Comment: @Bergi It is ES6 anyway. I doubt that there is an browser not supporting HTMLElement correctly, but implementing the full ES6. The same goes for `forEach`. Though you make a valid point here I guess.